# belongsTo method returning null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two model one named `Customer` second one is `Website`

Relationship between them is, `Customer` hasMany `Website` while `Website` belongsTo `Customer`

This is how I am doing this

```
class Website extends \Eloquent {
    use SubscriptionBillableTrait;

    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function customermodel()
    {
        // Return an Eloquent relationship.
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer')
    }

}
```

`Customer` model

```
use Mmanos\Billing\CustomerBillableTrait;
class Customer extends \Eloquent {
    use CustomerBillableTrait;
    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function websites() {
        return $this->hasMany('Website');
    }

}
```

When I try to access `Customer` by relationship like this

```
$website = Website::find(1);
return dd($website->customermodel);
```

It returns null

Note:I am using Laravel 4

Comment: Shouldn't those class names from the Eloquent relationship contain a fully qualified namespace `$this->belongsTo('App\Customer');` (this would most likely apply only if you're using Laravel 5, but you haven't specified that).

Comment: Use the fullnamespace when declaring the relationship, such as, `$this->hasMany('App\Models\Website');` and `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer');`. Does that work?

Comment: @Bogdan I am using Laravel 4 so I don't think this would be the trigger

Comment: Have you tried specifying your local key as in `return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'local_key')`?

Comment: Does your `websites` table have a field called `customer_id`? Also, are you sure website 1 has a related customer?

Comment: @JakeOpena - I just added `customer_id` and it worked as you mentioned - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$website = Website::find(1)->with('customermodel');
return dd($website->customermodel);
```

Comment: Two issues: First, eager loading won't help. Accessing the `$website->customermodel` attribute will lazy load the data, and then send it to the `dd()` method. Second, `find()` will return the model. You are then calling `with()` on the model, which will return a new query builder, so the next line will try to access the `customermodel` attribute on the query builder, which will throw an exception. You need to use the `with()` method before the method that actually retrieves the data: `Website::with('customermodel')->find(1)`.